# dynamically remove "open" class on AngularJS ui-bootstrap's dropdown

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm currently using UI-Bootstrap datepicker and dropdown. When I click the dropdown, shows the menu. While the menus or selections are visible, I click on calendar datepicker. The dropdown menu doesn't disappear. It stays open. However, if I click calendar datepicker first which shows the calendar dates, then I click on my dropdown, the calendar goes away which is what we would normally expect.

So, I investigated the dropdown in chrome dev tools. I noticed that when it's visible, it adds open to class.

```
<span class="btn-grp open">
```

Now when dropdown is not visible, it removes the open

```
<span class="btn-grp">
```

So I was thinking to dynamically remove open upon click on datepicker calendar via the open() I have. However, I am not sure how to reference to "open". Don't know if I should use ng-class since it's already being added dynamically by UI-bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

If your span has an id you can use jQuery to do it.

```
  <span id="myspan" class="open btn-grp">

  jQuery('#myspan').removeClass('open');
```

That will remove 'open' if it exists